# C: Binary Search and Binary Insertion

Tags: c, linked-list, binary-search

I'm currently working on solving the [Distinct Powers Question (29)](https://projecteuler.net/problem=29) on Project Euler. The problem involves finding the number of distinct products for (a^b) where (2 < a < 100) and (2 < b < 100). I initially created an algorithm that successfully handles factorization and checks for duplications. However, as I attempted to enhance the program's performance using linked lists and binary search, I encountered issues leading to a core dump. Despite efforts to identify logical flaws, I couldn't resolve the problem.

Here's the code snippet I'm working with:

````
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define A_MIN 2
#define A_MAX 100
#define B_MIN 2
#define B_MAX 100

struct Node {
    int *data;
    struct Node *next;
    struct Node *previous;
};

void primeFactor(int *arr, int num) {
    for (int k = 2; k <= num; ++k) {
        while (num % k == 0) {
            num /= k;
            arr[k] += 1;
        }
    }
}

int compareArrays(const int *arr1, const int *arr2, int size) {
    for (int k = 0; k < size; ++k) {
        if (arr2[k] < arr1[k]) {
            return -1; // arr2 is left of arr1
        } else if (arr1[k] < arr2[k]) {
            return 1; // arr2 is right of arr1
        }
    }
    return 0; // arr2 is arr1
}

void insertSorted(struct Node **head, const int *arr, int size, int *listLength) {
    struct Node *current = *head;

    int pos = 0;
    int left = 0;
    int right = *listLength;

    int comparison = -3;
    
    while (current != NULL && left < right) {
        int mid = (left + right) / 2;
        while (pos < mid) {
            current = current->next;
            pos++;
        }
        while (pos > mid) {
            current = current->previous;
            pos--;
        }
        comparison = compareArrays(current->data, arr, size);
        if (comparison == 1) { // arr2 is right of arr1
            left = mid + 1;
        } else if (comparison == -1) { // arr2 is left of arr1
            right = mid;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    struct Node *prev = (current != NULL) ? current->previous : NULL;
    struct Node *nxt = (current != NULL) ? current->next : NULL;

    if (comparison != 0) {
        struct Node *newNode = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        if (newNode == NULL) {
            perror("Memory allocation error");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        newNode->data = (int *)malloc(size * sizeof(int));
        if (newNode->data == NULL) {
            perror("Memory allocation error");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        memcpy(newNode->data, arr, size * sizeof(int));

        if (comparison == -1) { // perform insert left
            newNode->next = current;
            if (current != NULL) {
                current->previous = newNode;
            }
            if (prev == NULL) {
                *head = newNode;
            } else {
                prev->next = newNode;
                newNode->previous = prev;
            }
        } else if (comparison == 1) { // perform insert right
            newNode->next = nxt;
            if (current != NULL) {
                current->next = newNode;
            }
            if (nxt != NULL) {
                nxt->previous = newNode;
            }
        } else { // no node exist yet. make node the head.
            printf("lol");
            *head = newNode;
            
        }

        (*listLength)++;
    }
}

void freeLinkedList(struct Node *head) {
    while (head != NULL) {
        struct Node *temp = head;
        head = head->next;
        free(temp->data);
        free(temp);
    }
}

int main() {
    struct Node *link_list = NULL;
    int size = A_MAX;
    int listLength = 0;

    for (int i = A_MIN; i <= A_MAX; ++i) {
        int arr[A_MAX] = {0};
        primeFactor(arr, i);

        for (int j = B_MIN; j <= B_MAX; ++j) {
            int *arr2 = (int *)malloc(size * sizeof(int));
            if (arr2 == NULL) {
                perror("Memory allocation error");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            for (int k = 0; k < size; ++k) {
                arr2[k] = arr[k] * j;
            }

            insertSorted(&link_list, arr2, size, &listLength);
        }
    }

    printf("%d\n", listLength);

    freeLinkedList(link_list);

    return 0;
}```
````

Comment: You may want: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree

Comment: How about not storing the factorizations at all?  It should be possible to analyze each one in light of the associated `a` and `b` to determine whether to count it (for that `a`, `b`). This is basically an exercise in choosing a canonical `a`, `b` pair for each result.  I think the one with the maximum in-range `a` would be a workable choice.

Comment: As for the program you've actually written, Valgrind is a useful tool for detecting memory-use errors in running programs.  This would be an opportune time to add it to your tool belt.  You will get the most information out of valgrind if you run it on a binary that contains debug symbols.

Comment: Your prime factor array needs to be large enough to store the largest prime you will encounter.  That means its size must be one higher.  It happens to work because `A_MAX` is not a prime, but if it were, then you'd be writing past the end of the array when `i` in `main` is `A_MAX`.  For example, if `A_MAX` is `101`, this will break.

Comment: Usage of linked list and sorting it would just spiral up the time complexity, rather I suggest you to go for binary-search tree.
PS: [my approach in c++](https://onlinegdb.com/LIznK0bAa)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One logical flaw, which can definitely cause issues such as a core dump occurring, is with the following section of code in your `insertSorted` function:

```c
        memcpy(newNode->data, arr, size * sizeof(int));

        if (comparison == -1) { // perform insert left
            newNode->next = current;
            if (current != NULL) {
                current->previous = newNode;
            }
            if (prev == NULL) {
                *head = newNode;
            } else {
                prev->next = newNode;
                newNode->previous = prev;
            }
        } else if (comparison == 1) { // perform insert right
            newNode->next = nxt;
            if (current != NULL) {
                current->next = newNode;
            }
            if (nxt != NULL) {
                nxt->previous = newNode;
            }
        } else { // no node exist yet. make node the head.
            printf("lol");
            *head = newNode;
            
        }
```

The code uses `malloc` to allocate memory for `newNode` but, as indicated in the [malloc](https://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) man page,

> *The memory is not initialized.*

Since `comparison` can only be 0, -1 or 1, and this code is within the conditional `if (comparison != 0) {`, then the final `else` should never be executed. As such, the value of `newNode->next` is always set to a valid value. However, this is *not* always the case for `newNode->previous`. For example, if `comparison == -1`, then `newNode->previous` is only set if `prev != NULL`.

This means that `newNode->previous` may be uninitialized, thus using it such as with the `current = current->previous;` line earlier in `insertSorted`, can cause invalid memory to be accessed.

This issue can easily be fixed. Note that replacing your `malloc` call with [calloc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/calloc) which "... initializes all bytes in the allocated storage to zero" is an option, but as [Neil's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78076999/c-binary-search-and-binary-insertion/78077291#comment137646905_78077291) states

> Even `calloc` is not guaranteed to initialize null pointers; it works on most computers because null is very probably 0, ([5.13](https://c-faq.com/null/varieties.html)).

Thus, to be more robust, it's better to instead add the line `newNode->previous = NULL;` just after the `memcpy(newNode->data, arr, size * sizeof(int));` line in my specified section of your code.

Also, to make it more clear when casually reading the code that `newNode->next` is always initialized, and to help ensure later code changes don't break your code, I suggest adding the line `newNode->next = NULL;` initially as well.

Comment: @Neil Thanks for the reminder about that issue. As such, I've updated my answer to not recommend on relying on `calloc`, and I've also quoted the first sentence of your comment.

Answer (score 3):

#### General Comments

You use a binary search on your linked list to locate the insertion point for the next node.  Binary search is efficient when you have random access to the items, but much less so when you don't.  A linear search would be simpler to implement in your case, and possibly faster, too.

Even though your linked list does not use a dummy head node, you could provide one temporarily for the purposes of your linked list operations.  That could provide for cleaner code by removing the need for special-case handling of an empty list.

You use an inefficient representation for your prime factorizations: an array of `A_MAX` exponents.  There will be non-zero exponents only for primes, however, so you could easily get away with much shorter arrays, where each element corresponded to a prime.

#### The main issue

In many cases, your program fails to initialize the `previous` pointers of its dynamically allocated list nodes.  In some cases, it fails to initialize the `next` pointer, too.  `malloc()` does not initialize the allocated memory for you.  `calloc()` initializes it to all-byte-zero, but C does not define what that means as a pointer representation, so even with `calloc()` you would need to explicitly assign values to the pointer members of your allocated nodes.

#### Additional considerations

You don't need to store or compare factorizations at all, though I would still compute them.  You can determine directly from each factorization of an *a*<sup>*b*</sup> whether it will have been counted also as an *a'*<sup>*b'*</sup> where *a'* < *a*:

- compute the greatest common denominator, *d*(*a*), of all the non-zero exponents in the prime factorization of *a*.  This will often be 1.
- There is then a positive integer *a*<sub>0</sub> such that *a*<sub>0</sub><sup>*d*(*a*)</sup> = *a*.  There is no smaller positive integer *r* such that *a* is an integer power of *r*.
- *a*<sup>*b*</sup> is, of course, also an integer power of *a*<sub>0</sub>: *a*<sub>0</sub><sup>*d*(*a*)*b*</sup>.
- Let *x*(*a*) = *d*(*a*)*b*.  You will avoid counting any duplicates if you count only those *a*<sup>*b*</sup> where *b* is the smallest divisor of *x*(*a*) such that *x*(*a*) / *b* <= *b*<sub>max</sub>.  Where that is not the case, there is some power of *a*<sub>0</sub> less than *a* for which *a*<sup>*b*</sup> will have been counted.

Answer (score 1):

this is what my code looks like with John Omielan's suggestions! Fail to initialize the attribute of the node is the root cause of the core dump.

```c
void insertSorted(struct Node **head, const int *arr, int size, int *listLength) {
    int comparison = -1;
    // unchanged code goes here.
    if (comparison != 0) {
        // more unchanges code goes here.
        if (comparison == -1) { // perform insert left
            newNode->next = current;
            if (current == NULL) {
                newNode->next = NULL;
            }else{
                newNode->next = current;                
                current->previous = newNode;
            }
            if (prev == NULL) {
                newNode->previous = NULL;
                *head = newNode;
            } else {
                newNode->previous = prev;
                prev->next = newNode;
            }
        } else if (comparison == 1) { // perform insert right
            newNode->next = nxt;
            if (current == NULL) {
                newNode->previous = NULL;
                *head = newNode;
            }else{
                newNode->previous = current;
                current->next = newNode;
            }

            if (nxt == NULL) {
                newNode->next = NULL;
            }else{
                newNode->next = nxt;
                nxt->previous = newNode;
            }
        }

        (*listLength)++;
    }
}
```